# Alias for primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does SQL Server have alias for the primary key?

I need it in

```
EXEC('UPDATE ' + @Table + ' SET StatusId = ' + @StatusId + ' WHERE primaryKey = ' + @EntityId)
```

Comment: Is your column actually named `primaryKey`, or are you talking generally about `Primary Keys`? This is unclear.

Comment: Generally about primary keys. I need generic name which means primary key

Comment: Bearing in mind that primary keys may have more than column, you can probably select something from the system tables.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that a primary key may consist of multiple columns so there cannot be a single alias for the PK.  In the case of a single-column identity column primary key, you can use $IDENTITY as the alias.  For a `ROWGUIDCOL` surrogate key, use $ROWGUID.